# Picasso Target has been garbage collected

Tags: android, image, loading

Good day.I have an google map with cluster manager.Simple one,where i use the cluster to draw markers grouped or not.Anyway i got an method callback from cluster manager which is the Cluster item render one.Inside that callback i am applying custom image to the marker:The user image inside marker.I found Picasso to be the best to handle bitmap loading and at the same time got me lots of headache.I am using `Target` class from Picasso to initiate the bitmap callbacks:`OnPreLoad,OnFail,OnBitmapLoaded`.The issue is that on first cluster item render the `onBitmapLoaded` not called and generally it is never gets called unless it has been touched second time.On first time nothing happens,no callback is triggered except `OnPreLoad` and by googling i found that the great Picasso holds weak reference to the class.I tried all the examples of the google:Making Target reference strong(getting the initialazation of class out of method and init the class inside my class like the follows)

```
    @Override
protected void onClusterItemRendered(MarkerItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
    mMarker = marker;
    mMarkerItem = clusterItem;

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(clusterItem.getImageUrl()).transform(new CircleTransformation()).into(target);
}



private Target target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBitmapLoaded: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBitmapFailed: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareLoad: ");
    }
};
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MarkerItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
    markerOptions.icon(item.getIcon());
}
```

At this point i get the same result....Sometimes the bitmap loaded and sometimes not.Mostly not...
Anyway i have tried to implement the interface class to my own class as follows:

```
public  class PicassoMarkerView implements com.squareup.picasso.Target {
private static final String TAG = "MarkerRender";
private Bitmap mMarkerBitmap;
private ClusterManager<MarkerItem> mClusterManager;
private MarkerItem mMarkerItem;
private Marker mMarker;

public PicassoMarkerView() {

}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return mMarker.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof PicassoMarkerView) {
        Marker marker = ((PicassoMarkerView) o).mMarker;
        return mMarker.equals(marker);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
            mMarkerBitmap.getWidth() - 15, (int) (mMarkerBitmap.getHeight() / 1.5 - 15),
            false);
    mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(overlay(mMarkerBitmap, scaledBitmap, 8, 7)));
    Log.d(TAG, "onBitmapLoaded: ");
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBitmapFailed: ");
}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareLoad: ");
}


private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2, int left, int top) {
    Bitmap res = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1.getWidth(), bitmap1.getHeight(),
            bitmap1.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(res);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, left, top, null);

    return res;
}


public void setMarkerBitmap(Bitmap markerBitmap) {
    this.mMarkerBitmap = markerBitmap;
}

public void setClusterManager(ClusterManager<MarkerItem> clusterManager) {
    this.mClusterManager = clusterManager;
}

public void setMarkerItem(MarkerItem markerItem) {
    this.mMarkerItem = markerItem;
}

public void setMarker(Marker marker) {
    this.mMarker = marker;
}
```

}

Unfortunatally this is not working either...Same result...So please dear friends can you give me an working example of this?As far as i could google,the issue mostly happens to the user which try to do this inside loop and my `onClusterItemRender` some sort of loop lets say as it is triggered every time marker is visible to user,so yeah it is triggered several times and as fast as loop so give me some idea please and help me out...

Important to mention that i do not need to use methods from picasso like `fetch(),get()` as they are not necessary and not fitting the purpose of the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered similar issue and holding reference to the target didn't help at all.

The purpose of my project was to use 2 different image downloading api's to show an images gallery and to give the user the ability to choose which api to use.

Beside Picasso I used Glide, and I was amazed by the results, Glide's api worked flawlessly in every aspect wile Picasso gave me hell (that was my first time using Glide, I usually used Picasso so far, seems like today it's gonna change ^^ ).

So my suggestion to you is:

1. Use glide over Picasso (no such weak reference on their target).
2. Since I had to use both libraries I ended up using get() in an handler, not sure if it will help you but it solved my problem:

---

```
handlerThread = new HandlerThread(HANDLER_THREAD_NAME);
handlerThread.start();

Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = picasso.with(appContext).load(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                //do whatever you wanna do with the picture.
                //for me it was using my own cache
                imageCaching.cacheImage(imageId, bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Saved my day. Now I can combine this with RxJava